# Is there a way to save iPad console logs for a long time period?

Tags: ios, logging, console

I want to run some automation for 24h and then use the console logs, is anyone know how to save the logs?

I already tried to use Organiser console and iPhone Configuration utility.

The app throw a lot of logs messages I want to parse it after 24h run.

Please note I have no access to source code.

10x

Comment: Without access to the source code I think you're hamstrung.  You could keep the device attached to your Mac, dump everything to the Organizer console, then export to a text file.  Short of that, I'm not sure there is another way.

Comment: Already did it, not good enough.
It only work for a short run otherwise the first logs get erased. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this question, I manage to find some github project who dump all ios logs to terminal.

https://github.com/benvium/libimobiledevice-macosx/tree/8507dd21f9f3198e988ad68b306613097721523c

I hope it will help someone.